# How to refer a component with a variable in React?

Tags: reactjs

I have a separate file in my project with variables, and I have created a list of different forms for signup purpose.

There is a parent component which imports these variables, and based on the list item, I want to render a separate child component. Currently I am doing it with implementing a long if-else condition, but this makes the code really WET.

I was thinking if it is possible to tag the names of the child components along with the list items in the variables file itself, or some other implementation, as I have uniform component names as with the list elements.

Comment: Do you have a simple example we can work with and fix up for you?

Comment: I've done this with a look-up table before, like `const VARIANT = { example: Example, alt: Alternate }`. Then later `const SubType = VARIANT[...]` so you can `<SubType ...>`.